# Using RAML to describe a JSON-RPC service over HTTPS

Tags: json, rest, https, json-rpc, raml

I am trying to use RAML to concretely describe various cryptocurrency exchange APIs <strike>who</strike> that all use a different format (non standardized) to present and document their API. I have had an easy time doing this for RESTful APIs (as that is mostly what RAML is for to my understanding) but am having a difficult time doing this for an API that uses JSON-RPC over https.

First off...is this possible and/or feasible?

If it is possible and/or feasible, is the following the correct way to do it? It seems to be limiting because I don't know of a way to enumerate the possible methods and their *respective* parameters, I can only declare that there is a method parameter.

As suggested by David Dossot, I tried using a JSON schema instead of queryParameters. Here is my attempt (I still do not see a way to enumerate/describe the individual methods of the API, I only have the power to express that there is a method keyword and it is a string (similar to the limitation I had with the queryParameters route).

```
#%RAML 0.8

title: BTC-China API
baseUri: https://data.btcchina.com/data/

baseUri: https://api.btcchina.com/api_trade_v1.php

/api_trade_v1.php:
  post:
    description: The JSON-RPC BTC-China API.
    headers:
      Authorization:
        description: |
          Blah blah

        example: Basic PGFjY2Vzc2tleT46PGhhc2g+
    body:
      application/json:
        schema: |
          {
           "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
           "title": "JSON-RPC Request",
           "description" : "A JSON-RPC request to the BTC-China API.",

           "type" : "object",
           "required" : ["jsonrpc", "method"],
           "properties" : {
             "jsonrpc" : { "enum" : ["2.0"] },
             "method" : {
               "type" : "string"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "number"
              },
              "params" : {
                "type" : ["array", "object"]
              }
            }
          }

    responses:
       200:
          body:
            application/json:
              example: |
                {"result":12345,"id":"1"} 

        401:
          body:
            text/plain:
              example: 401 Unauthorized - invalid access key
```

Now that I am using a schema, I still do not see a way that I can enumerate or describe the individual methods of the API.

Update 8/13/2014:

Attempt to use JSON $refs and sub-schemas (still running into an issue of how to link the method with its associated parameters and how to describe the method, etc. as the JSON Schema v4 only has 3 validation parameters for a string (the type that method is in JSON-RPC, it's not an object), maxLength, minLength, and pattern. None are expressive enough to explain what the method is/does and the option/available parameters for it)

```
body:
  application/json:
    schema: |
      {
       "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
       "title": "JSON-RPC Request",
       "description" : "A JSON-RPC request to the BTC-China API.",

       "type" : "object",
       "required" : ["jsonrpc", "method"],
       "properties" : {
         "jsonrpc" : {
           "enum" : ["2.0"]
         },
         "method" : {
           "type" : "string",
           "oneOf" : [
               { "$ref": "#/definitions/getbalance" },
               { "$ref": "#/definitions/withdrawal" },
               { "$ref": "#/definitions/depositaddress" }
             ]
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "number"
          },
          "params" : {
            "type" : ["array", "object"]
          }
        }
        "definitions" : {
          "getbalance": {},
          "withdrawal": {},
          "depositaddress": {}
      }
```

Comment: Have you run this through a RAML parser/validator? The multiple `baseUri` elements look incorrect.

Comment: Ah that was a mistake from experimentation, thanks...I have removed that!

Comment: I changed from queryParameters to a schema but am still having the same issue.

Comment: You can use `oneOf` to select a sub-schema, one per particular request. See: http://json-schema.org/example2.html

Comment: This seemed like a logical and good idea, but after experimenting and contemplating it seems I don't gain anything. The "method" property is a string, not an object. Therefore, in the sub-schema (as per JSON Schema v4) it can only have 3 validation parameters: maxLength, minLength, and pattern. None of these will enable me to describe the method, nor "link it" with its associated parameters. Still very at a dead end =(

Comment: I was hoping `oneOf` could be usable at a higher level to define the whole request object, not just its method. I guess you're painfully rediscovering why JSON-RPC is a bad idea in the first place :'( Because, by the same token, how would you define and associate response schemas to requests? That's why REST is superior, as request/responses are strongly associated to distinct resources. But of course you do not need to be lectured on this. Sorry for the digression.

Comment: First of all David I want to sincerely thank you for the effort you put into answering all of my questions and staying on track with me. For that I am going to certainly mark your answer as "the answer". In light of our discoveries I am going to add a meta-layer between my application and the exchange. This will take the form of a JSON file that specifies the exchange name, exchange API version, and exchange API TYPE where type can be REST, JSON-RPC, and anything else that pops up "in the wild". Then depending on the type, it will either have a RAML or JSON-WSP depending on it's type.

Comment: If you have any suggestions for description languages for JSON-RPC specifically, let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I believe the link in my answer is a reasonable attempt at trying to specify a JSON-RPC API. It's not JSON schema unfortunately but it could be used as an "out-of-band" descriptor, since RAML only supports JSON or XML schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `queryParameters` to try to describe the JSON body entities used in the JSON-RPC protocol but instead use JSON Schema.

Reading this may also help: http://www.jsonrpc.org/historical/json-schema-service-descriptor.html

Comment: I understand that using JSON Schema to describe a JSON-RPC API is a good way to do that. However, it does not at all address my original question of:

Is it possible to describe a JSON-RPC API (over https) with _RAML_? And if it is possible, is the code snippet I posted on the right track to do so.

I am not asking the general question of how to describe a JSON-RPC API using various description languages, I am asking the specific question of doing so with RAML (http://raml.org/).

Comment: JSON Schema is part of RAML: since you are not using it in the above spec, I thought relevant to mention it as it seems you didn't intend to use it.

Comment: Okay sorry for my misunderstanding. You are suggesting to use the JSON Schema aspect of RAML to describe this JSON-RPC API...interesting =)...for reference the API specification is here: http://btcchina.org/api-trade-documentation-en If you have the time, if you could show me an example by describing one of the methods (say deposit, or withdrawal, or whatever) using JSON Schema in the RAML that would get me off to a running start. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may describe your JSON RPC service with another one specifications:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-WSP
- http://www.simple-is-better.org/json-rpc/jsonrpc20-schema-service-descriptor.html
- https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WADL

RAML is very powerful and over engineering for common usage. How about using JSON-WSP for example?